# GET Request in node.js is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, curl, httprequest

I'm having big troubles loading a page through Node.js. This is the code of my Node.js Application, please note it works if I try to load other resources (like www.google.com) so the question is specific to the domain name www.egopay.com:

```
 var http = require('http');
 var options = {
    hostname: 'www.egopay.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/',
    method: 'GET'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
    console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
    });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

// write data to request body
req.write('data\n');
req.write('data\n');
req.end();
```

Using cURL it works, Node.js won't.

Around one minute after the request this error shows up:

```
problem with request: read ECONNRESET
```

Comment: You said `GET` request in title of your question, but actually sends `POST` in your code. Maybe, just check things?

Comment: Both don't work, I have changed the code to reflect the question title.

Comment: why are you writing a body for a GET request? technically it is allowed but is probably blocked by the server

Comment: Just opening this URL in browser redirects me to https site. Maybe, your `curl` command follows redirect (even though it is not so w/o additional flag). Hardly node's `http.requst` handle redirects by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I made the same request, but added a user-agent to the headers, I got a response, that made it clear what was happening.  Try adding this line to your options:

```
headers: {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.62 Safari/537.36'},
```

Basically, they have an nginx server that redirects you to an HTTPS site with the same URL.  Your not getting a response without including a user agent is probably a bug in the nginx deployment for that site.  I can explain it no other way, as I cannot recreate the circumstances in Chrome or Firefox.  Even when overriding with an empty user-agent.  I imagine it is the difference between an empty string and an undefined string.  Node is sending the header's field as completely undefined, whereas the browsers I'm trying to replicate with are only sending an empty string.  Again, can't recreate, but this is my best guess.

Comment: Hmmm, you have me thinking, we may be able to DDOS that site pretty easy, anybody wanna stress test egopay.com?

Comment: Why would it be easy?

Comment: Well, the http link they have redirecting has a clear bug.  Their real site would be fine, but their nginx server is broken, and would be easier(perhaps easy is an understatement, but easier) to DDOS than one that responds quickly with a 404 to malformed requests.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues with requests in Node js so i wrote this npm package:

https://npmjs.org/package/curljs

Hope it helps!

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much. Anyway, I'm still wondering what's wrong with the http.request() method.